# Unable to put date in <input type="date"> field in Firefox using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am sending date of birth to an input element using selenium, data is getting entered in Chrome and Edge but in firefox that input element has an inbuilt datepicker and I am not able to inspect that default datepicker (right click doesn't work on datePicker and couldn't find any code for it). The input element is not taking values and I can't get the html element so I'm unable to fill the field.

Can anyone help me with this?

[image: Firefox's datePicker]

Comment: Please show any code you practiced so far.

Comment: when the websites have different components in different browser(i guess through a servserside browserswitch) you have to handle them seperately. the site seems not to be very testautomation friendly, but this is common. you need a testautmation browserswitch on your side than. and how you have to handle thos components, depends on them, there is not "one matches all"

Comment: In 2022, I stuck in the same issue entering the data format in Firefox webdriver. Anyone solved this issue without any trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You handle this issue with the following trick:

- Change the input type from date to text using JavaScriptExecutor by Selenium
- After changing the element type to text the change the date field by sending text with the same format needed to change value, use sendKeys("dd/mm/yyyy").

OR try to use Selenium Actions move to element and click.

Comment: Can you open new question with your case?

Answer (score 10):

For Firefox, the date format is yyyy-mm-dd , regardless placeholder. I read Flaburgan's comment in https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1070 and searched documents, tested okay.

```
WebElement dateOfBirth = driver.findElement(By.name("dob"));
dateOfBirth.sendKeys("2012-12-24");
```